# What is a polyphase induction motor? How does it work and how do you build one?

Tags: electromagnetism

I want to understand how the polyphase induction motor works because I want to build one if possible or at least understand how it works and what materials it comprises of.

Comment: Would you like me to move this to [engineering.se] where it might be on topic?

Comment: This clearly belongs into electrical engineering, but I doubt you will get much help with the building part there, either. These motors can be bought cheaply these days, so it's not even clear why you would want to build one, yourself.

Comment: The principles behind how an induction motor works is a very good example of Lenz's law in action and so is in the realm of Physics.  As a construction project it might be engineering but one only needs to look at this video to see how to make one for demonstration purposes.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-eTLmJC2cQ

Answer (score 1):

A way of understanding how an induction motor works is to apply Lenz’s law which states that the induced current will always try to oppose the change producing it.

This [first video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5O0DJ65RdA) shows that a conducting disc will always try and follow a moving magnet.
The moving magnet induces a current in the disc.
That induced current produces a magnetic field which tries to oppose the change producing it which is a magnetic field which is decreasing in magnitude.
The induced pole due to magnetic field is of the opposite polarity to that of the moving magnet and so there is a force of attraction.
The attractive force on the disc makes it move towards the moving magnet.
The disc tries to follow the magnet.

The [next video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdDd8ufhXCg) shows how to produce the same effect by using two electromagnets which both have an alternating current passing through them but there is a difference in phase between the currents.
If a part of the disc finds itself in a position where the magnetic field due to one electromagnet is decreasing whilst the adjacent electromagnet has an increasing magnetic field the disc will rotate towards the region where the magnetic field is increasing because that would “oppose” the change producing the induced current – the decreasing magnetic field due to the first electromagnet.

With a [three phase supply](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P-eTLmJC2cQ) one can get the disc to “chase” the magnetic field which is inducing the current at a number of positions on the disc and so make the motor more efficient and powerful.